# When I @ConfigProperty in the result i got null

Tags: java, maven, config

I want take value from properties file but when i'm trying do it i got null, where is the mistake? It's maven project.

[image: My IDEA view]

Comment: Why application.properties in META-INF directory instead of src/main/resources?

Comment: Does it work when getting the object of `ReportService` using dependency injection instead of you invoking the constructor?

Comment: @chptr-one If application.properties is in resource it also doesn't work

Comment: @dan1st how to get object by using dependency injection? It is trival version now i'm testing it in Main class

Comment: If the project is loaded by spring, you could add `@Component`. to the class and autowire that class.

Comment: It's maven project

Comment: Please specify the exact name of the package, from where you take annotation @ConfigProperty. Or just show your pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your application.properties file `src\main\resources` instead of `src\main\resources\META-INF`

Make sure your class `ReportService` is a getting registered as a bean (Generally `@Service` \ `@Component` annotation) and try injecting the bean using `@Autowired` annotation

Comment: And i still got null, It isn't Spring project